# Does Damage Reduction Stack?

Tags: dead-winter-rpg

In the *DWRPG Rules Guide*, there's a bunch of gear that gives Damage Reduction. In fact, almost every non-light armor (even skinplates) gives at least a bit of DR. This is also true for most Armor-enhancing magic itens, feats and class abilities (Like *Steel Spirit* from the Fighter, the Dwarven racial feat *Tough Skin* and the mythic artifact *Sovereign Shield*).

Most of the items / class features / feats that give DR are for tank-types. That can be seen on the prerequisites for those things, like Tough Skin requiring Con 15 and Steel Spirit only working while you are wearing Heavy Armor.

In some cases, it is clear that the DR is intended to stack (as in the Steel Spirit case). But does it always stack, or are there cases in which the DRs don't stack at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it always stacks.

Damage Reduction in Dead Winter RPG is way more common that it is in Pathfinder or D&D 3.5. Almost every armor bonus to your AC (except from Light Armor) will give you some form of Damage Reduction—some more, others less. All of these bonuses stack.

Since most of these bonuses to your DR will normally be small, when they are combined they will give you a good overall defense, but not something that makes you invulnerable.

DR works like this:

- All non-light armors give a DR equal to half its bonus to AC—armor that grants +4 to your AC will give you DR 2/-. Enchanted armor adds its enhancement bonus to its DR, so a suit of Superior Half-Plate (+6 AC, +3 enhancement, total +9 AC) would give you a total of +6 to your DR.
- Any magic item that gives an Armor Bonus will also increase your DR, but won't raise your AC if your armor is better. Example: If you are wearing a Superior Half Plate (+9 AC, DR 5/-) and a *Trinket of the Crocodile* (+4 AC as an Armor Bonus, DR 2/-), the AC bonus of the Half Plate and the Trinket won't stack, so you still have +9 AC. Their DR stack, however, so you would end up with a total DR of 8/-.
- DR gained from class features stacks with everything. So, a fighter using the *Trinket* and the Half Plate as above, who also has the class feature *Steel Spirit* (which adds his Con modifier as DR) and Con 18, would have a total of DR 12/-.

Keep in mind that DR is useless against magic-based damage. A simple *Magic Missile* will pierce your defenses and do full damage.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this system.